# Calling object methods inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I have an object defined by other and I want to create a dictionary that calls this methods. I know that I can do a lot of if else to do this but I would like to keep my code clean. I'll explain better with an example.

```
#object creation
my_obj = Foo()
dict = {0: my_obj.func1(x=5), 1: my_obj.func1(x=2)}
```

Then I want to use the dictionary to execute those methods:

```
#imagine the user choosing 0 or 1
y = input()
#execute the method
dict[y]
```

Of course this isn't working but I would like to understand if this is possible because online I can find only stuff related to calling function and not method with a dictionary.

Comment: You should wonder at what time the function is executed: the first time it is used with its parameters. Here the functions are executed at that point: `dict = {0: my_obj.func1(x=5), 1: my_obj.func1(x=2)}` and `dict[0]` only gives the (saved) result.

Comment: As a side note, don't use `dict` as name. Also when you do `dict[y]` you access the element with key `y`. And in your case keys are ints and `y` is a `str`(being return value from `input()`). So _isn't working_ refers to what exactly? Convert `y` to int or use strings as keys. And if the keys are int like 0, 1, ... you can as well use list

Comment: _"Of course this isn't working"_ Why? The error, that you haven't included, should be a `KeyError` (otherwise, please include it in your question) and use the comment of _buran_ to fix it, for ex `int(input())`